# Call SSL_shutdown() hang, client still in FIN_WAIT2 status

Tags: ssl

In my ActiveUpdate module(download files from server), close OpenSSL connection will hang(wait beyond 2 hour) if server drop the FIN package.

Pseudo code of SSL Connection close

```
def  ssl_close():
if (!SSL_shutdown(m_ssl)):
    …
    shutdown(SSL_get_fd(m_ssl), SHUT_WR);
    SSL_shutdown(m_ssl)
    ...
```

netstat output for the hung connection

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.133.135:52453   10.203.136.169:4122     FIN_WAIT2   off (0.00/0/0)
```

> https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_shutdown.html
>
> In order to complete the bidirectional shutdown handshake, SSL_shutdown() must be called again. 
>   If the underlying BIO is blocking, SSL_shutdown() will only return once the handshake step has been finished or an error occurred.

If call SSL_shutdown() once, it will not hang, does it have any impact on memory and connection resources?

Is there a timeout mechanism to control the SSL_shutdown() in OpenSSL, or a better way?

Answer (score 2):

The first SSL_shutdown will cause the sending of the shutdown alert to the peer to signal the peer that no more SSL data are coming - similar to sending a FIN or doing a shutdown SHUT_WR on a plain socket. The second SSL_shutdown will wait until it receives a shutdown alert from the peer.

To make sure the socket is fully alive so that the peer will send the SSL shutdown alert and you'll receive it, I recommend to only shutdown the underlying socket once the second SSL_shutdown completed. I.e. first fully downgrade the socket from SSL to plain, then close the plain socket.

Answer (score 2):

> ... if server drop the FIN package.

I don't believe the problem you are seeing is due to a lost `FIN`. I suspect (as Steffen) you are waiting for a `close_notify` form the client, but the client did not send it.

---

> if (!SSL_shutdown(m_ssl)) ...

`SSL_shutdown` returns -1, 0 and 1; not 0 and 1.

---

> If call SSL_shutdown() once, it will not hang, does it have any impact on memory and connection resources?

I don't believe so, but it would probably be better to verify it under Valgrind or other leak detector tool.

---

> Is there a timeout mechanism to control the SSL_shutdown() in OpenSSL, or a better way?

I don't believe there's a timeout.

There are two strategies you can use:

1. You field the request and don't care about the client's `close_notify`
2. You want to follow the protocol to the letter, and want clients to do the same

Calling `SSL_shutdown` once is strategy 1. Just close the socket and be done with it.

Calling `SSL_shutdown` twice is strategy 2. The problem is, not all clients send it. Often times, they will just close the socket after they have read everything they requested.

You can detect the second situation by trapping a `SIGPIPE`. If there's a `SIGPIPE` on the connection, then the client closed the socket. Just call `SSL_shutdown` once.

Eric Rescorla goes into it in more detail at [An Introduction to OpenSSL Programming (Part I)](https://github.com/smbutton/DataCommProject/blob/master/openssl-examples-20020110/openssl-examples-20020110/part1.pdf). Here's the server-side code he offers:

```
51     r=SSL_shutdown(ssl);
52     if(!r){
53         /* If we called SSL_shutdown() first then
54            we always get return value of ’0’. In
55            this case, try again, but first send a
56            TCP FIN to trigger the other side’s
57            close_notify */
58         shutdown(s,1);
59         r=SSL_shutdown(ssl);
60     }
61
62     switch(r){
63     case 1:
64         break; /* Success */
65     case 0:
66     case -1:
67     default:
68         berr_exit("Shutdown failed");
69     }
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. I was in a strange situation. I was doing `SSL_shutdown()` followed by `socket->shutdown(), close()`. If I run such binary in Eclipse, then things were working fine. If the exactly same binary is ran from Ubuntu command line, then it was not working fine!!! Seeing your answer, I reversed the order. i.e. `socket->shutdown(), close()` followed by `SSL_shutdown()` & it worked.